# How to get path from different files in different directories?

Tags: c#, string, directory

I need to get path for each file in directories

> eg: c:/a/b/c/1.jar and c:/dir/bin/2.jar must be saved as string
>
> "c:/a/b/c/1.jar; c:/dir/bin/2.jar;..."

But the folders name may change in the future and I don't want to write this manually

Thanks for help

**EDIT 1:**
I've got the folder with few folders into. in each folder is files. I need to get all files directory in one string. eg: "dir1; dir2; dir3; ..."
but I can give only directory of main folder "c:/bin"

**EDIT 2:** Solved by Sayse

Comment: I don't understand your question clearly. Please clarify it. What do you have and what do you want?

Comment: I think you might want to take a look at [System.IO.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/system.io.path.aspx)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. Do you have a list of files and you want to get the directory for each file?

Comment: @WojtekWrona have you already tested one of the solutions below? I don't really get what you mean by "but I can give only name of main folder c:/folder". If you want to get all files whice are in the path c:/folder and below, use my method and say `DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\folder");` or use the method from Sayse and say `var allFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\folder","*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories);

Comment: So you have a list of folders and a list of names.  Store both delimited lists (semicolon may not work).  Then, read in each folder and scan it for all listed file names.  Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Directory.EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571.aspx)

```
var allFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory,
          "*.*", //also can use "*.jar" here for just jar files
            SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

If you wish for all files to be in one long string then you can use

```
var fileString = string.Join(",", allFiles);
```

If its only directories you want

```
var allDirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories("...",
    "*",
     SearchOption.AllDirectories);
var dirString = string.Join(";", allDirs);
```

Comment: If you add the files (path)name to a string (just like he wants it) and you're not allowed to access the file, it's kinda hard to keep the foreach-loop, since an exception pops up and stops the foreach-loop.

Comment: @rudi - This adds all filenames (with full path) to a list, I don't understand what your saying

Comment: I know that this adds all filenames to `allFiles`, but as I'm getting OP's questions, he wants to have them in a string -> _"c:/a/b/c/1.jar; c:/dir/bin/2.jar;"_ and seperate them with **;**

Comment: Quote: eg: c:/a/b/c/1.jar and c:/dir/bin/2.jar **must be saved as string** . I could be wrong and I get OP's question wrong... But in my opinion it doesn't really matter if it's stored in a list or in a string... Edit: I've used `string.Join` and I'm getting "UnauthorizedAccessException" when I'm trying to access the File "C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-18"

Comment: @Rudi  -I've given up on this lol, I know it works (may need extra EH), OP seems unresponsive

Comment: yeah, I also don't really get what he wants. The files? The folders? From where... Just one specific drive / location (like c:\windows) or all files on his computer (C:, D:, ...).

Comment: @WojtekWrona , you can accept the answer if you wish (click the tick outline below the voting arrows)

Comment: @WojtekWrona it would be great to know what you were actually looking for. `.....(",", allFiles);` or `.....(";", allDirs);`

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\");
        FullDirList(di, "*");
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.Read();
    }
    static string myfolders = "";// Your string, which inclueds the folders like this: "c:/a/b/c; c:/dir/bin;..."
    static string myfiles = ""; // Your string, which inclueds the file like this: "c:/a/b/c/1.jar; c:/dir/bin/2.jar;..."
    static List<FileInfo> files = new List<FileInfo>();  // List that will hold the files and subfiles in path
    static List<DirectoryInfo> folders = new List<DirectoryInfo>(); // List that hold direcotries that cannot be accessed
    static void FullDirList(DirectoryInfo dir, string searchPattern)
    {

        // Console.WriteLine("Directory {0}", dir.FullName);
        // list the files
        try
        {
            foreach (FileInfo f in dir.GetFiles(searchPattern))
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("File {0}", f.FullName);
                files.Add(f);
                myfiles += f.FullName + ";";
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Directory {0}  \n could not be accessed!!!!", dir.FullName);
            return;  // We alredy got an error trying to access dir so dont try to access it again
        }

        // process each directory
        // If I have been able to see the files in the directory I should also be able 
        // to look at its directories so I dont think I should place this in a try catch block
        foreach (DirectoryInfo d in dir.GetDirectories())
        {
            myfolders += d.FullName + ";";
            folders.Add(d);
            FullDirList(d, searchPattern);
        }
    }
}
```

`myfiles` includes all files , like "C:\MyProgram1.exe;C:\MyFolder\MyProgram2.exe;C:\MyFolder2\MyProgram2.dll"

`myfolder` inclueds all folders, like "C:\MyFolder;C:\MyFolder2";